# Are there any pattern/way for step by step process execution?

Tags: java, spring

I have an application with Java and Spring on a server side. This server has few modules and one of them is responsible for one process execution. One from modules has a process which starts from one of endpoints and has few steps.

Something like this:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "movie")
public class MovieController {

    private final MovieService movieService;

    @GetMapping("step1")
    public ResponseEntity step1() {
        return movieService.step1();
    }

    @GetMapping("step2")
    public ResponseEntity step2() {
        return movieService.step2();
    }

    @GetMapping("step3")
    public ResponseEntity step3() {
        return movieService.step3();
    }

    @GetMapping("step4")
    public ResponseEntity step4() {
        return movieService.step4();
    }

    @GetMapping("step5")
    public ResponseEntity step5() {
        return movieService.step5();
    }
}
```

As you can see, each step can be started from UI in this case. But for now I need to add ability to run all steps from one end point. All steps depend on status of previous step and next step never must start if previous one was failed. That's why I'm looking for the best way to execute all steps.

I don't like this way:

```
@PostMapping("run")
public ResponseEntity runProcess() {
    movieService.step1();
    movieService.step2();
    movieService.step3();
    movieService.step4();
    return movieService.step5();
}
```

I thought about Spring Batch, I could separate each method of `movieService` to Spring Batch Steps and but are there any sense?

What is the right way to implement such problems?

Comment: you can call step2 from within step1, ...

Comment: @Stultuske, I have the interface `MovieService` which has methods for all steps. If I call next step from previous one I won't need to have interface with all methods because there are all in one class and can be private. In this case will appear a big chain of calls  of private methods, right? It is not a good solution in my opinion..

Comment: The results of step1-4 are intermediate results, correct? Then the builder pattern with lambdas might be applicable: http://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2014/11/02/builder-pattern-with-java-8-lambdas/.

Comment: The problem is your method return type (`ResponseEntity`). This is presentation layer work (even for a rest service) and you don't want to call the presentation layer from another service. It would be better to return a POJO (normal Java object) and have the JSON mapping logic convert that to the presentation format of the service - then you can also combine the steps and look at the return value of each step from a business layer perspective. And then you should return some more details to the caller in case of failure, so the caller can retry the step that failed by itself.

Comment: Try to Implement Graphql which give the ability to run all steps from one end point - https://github.com/facebook/graphql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with [State pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-state) and a class to embedded the logic inside. So you could call the change state function as many times as you want and you can also embedded the logic("if something fails") inside the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC comes with `AbstractWizardFormController` class to handle wizard form easily;

[See an example here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/):

```
public class UserController extends AbstractWizardFormController{

    public UserController(){
        setCommandName("userForm");
    }

    @Override
    protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {

        return new User();
    }
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView processFinish(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {

        //Get the data from command object
        User user = (User)command;
        System.out.println(user);

        //where is the finish page?
        return new ModelAndView("ResultForm", "user", user);
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView processCancel(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {

        //where is the cancel page?
        return new ModelAndView("WelcomePage");
    }

    @Override
    protected void validatePage(Object command, Errors errors, int page) {

        UserValidator validator = (UserValidator) getValidator();

        //page is 0-indexed
        switch (page) {
           case 0: //if page 1 , go validate with validatePage1Form
            validator.validatePage1Form(command, errors);
            break;
           case 1: //if page 2 , go validate with validatePage2Form
            validator.validatePage2Form(command, errors);
            break;
           case 2: //if page 3 , go validate with validatePage3Form
            validator.validatePage3Form(command, errors);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for resposne, sorry but I didn't write that I don't work with JSP. UI is implemented on AngularJS and it sends REST requests to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **custom exception** and throw that exception in case of failure in each method. For example .

**service:**

```
   public ResponseEntity step...() {
        if(failure){
          throw new CustomException("Error can't complete step 1");
        }
        return movieService.step1();
    }
```

**controller:**

```
public String runProcess() {
    try {
        movieService.step1();
        movieService.step2();
        movieService.step3();
        movieService.step4();
        movieService.step5();
    }catch(CustomException e){
      return e.getMessage();
    }

}
```